# SQL statements ignored in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

So i'm writing a function for oracle db but I get errors saying that the sql statements were ignored and so expressions are missing.

The function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getQueueNumber
(student IN VARCHAR,course IN CHAR) 
RETURN INT
IS
   queuePosition INT;
   date TIMESTAMP;
   BEGIN
       SELECT waitingDate INTO date
       FROM WaitingCourseStudent wcs 
       WHERE wcs.student=student AND wcs.course=course;
       IF SQL%NOTFOUND THEN queuePosition := NULL;
       ELSE
           SELECT COUNT(*) as pos
           INTO queuePosition
           FROM WaitingCourseStudent 
           WHERE waitingDate<=date;
      END IF;
      RETURN queuePosition;
END;
```

Full error message:

```
LINE/COL    ERROR
8/5     PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
8/29    PL/SQL: ORA-00936: missing expression
13/9    PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
16/20   PL/SQL: ORA-00936: missing expression
```

Comment: Please avoid declaring variables with reserved words. date is a reserved word.

Comment: Also, avoid naming your parameters exactly the same as your columns.

Comment: Name your parameters the same as the columns, but namespace them with the function name inside the SQL. ie "wcs.student= getQueueNumber.student"

Comment: You should probably combine the two queries into one also, for performance reasons. And do you not need to apply a predicate on the course for the second query, or you're counting all courses.

Comment: @DavidAldridge Aah, forgot about course, ofcourse i should check that too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're probably looking for, is error handling instead of just an if.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getQueueNumber
  (p_student IN VARCHAR, p_course IN CHAR) 
RETURN INT
IS
  queuePosition INT;
  v_date TIMESTAMP;
BEGIN
   BEGIN
      SELECT waitingDate INTO v_date
      FROM WaitingCourseStudent wcs 
      WHERE wcs.student = p_student AND wcs.course = p_course;
   EXCEPTION
      WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN RETURN NULL;
   END;

   SELECT COUNT(*) as pos
   INTO queuePosition
   FROM WaitingCourseStudent 
   WHERE waitingDate <= v_date;
   RETURN queuePosition;
END;
```

The inner BEGIN/END is for the exception handling. An exception can only be handled within a BEGIN/END block and since you needed to do something after your exception, you need an inner BEGIN/END. An alternative would be

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getQueueNumber
  (p_student IN VARCHAR, p_course IN CHAR) 
RETURN INT
IS
  queuePosition INT;
  v_date TIMESTAMP;
BEGIN
   SELECT waitingDate INTO v_date
   FROM WaitingCourseStudent wcs 
   WHERE wcs.student = p_student AND wcs.course = p_course;

   SELECT COUNT(*) as pos
   INTO queuePosition
   FROM WaitingCourseStudent 
   WHERE waitingDate <= v_date;
   RETURN queuePosition;

EXCEPTION
   WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN RETURN NULL;
END;
```

Comment: Ahh! Didn't know you could do that, worked perfectly :). I have some questions though. Did the renaming of the variable mean something or did you just not like the names. Also, why do you hav two BEGIN/END?

Comment: @SiXoS Adjusted my answer.

Comment: You don't need to rename the parameters if you namespace them with the function name when they're used inside a SQL statement. "wcs.student= getQueueNumber.student"

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT waitingDate INTO date <--- (date is reserved keyword for denoting oracle datatype of date)
FROM WaitingCourseStudent wcs 
   WHERE wcs.student=student AND wcs.course=course;
   IF SQL%NOTFOUND THEN queuePosition := NULL;
```

Alternate suggestion :

Prefix your variables with **v_** or something like that to avoid these kind of errors.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is as follows:

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getQueueNumber (vstudent IN VARCHAR,vcourse IN CHAR) 
RETURN INT
IS
   queuePosition INT;
   date1 TIMESTAMP;
   BEGIN
       SELECT waitingDate INTO date1 FROM WaitingCourseStudent WHERE student=vstudent AND course=vcourse;
       IF SQL%NOTFOUND THEN 
          queuePosition := NULL;
       ELSE
           SELECT COUNT(*) INTO queuePosition FROM WaitingCourseStudent WHERE waitingDate <= date1;
      END IF;
      RETURN queuePosition;
  exception
    when no_data_found then
      return -1;
    when others then
      return -1;
END;